# wait for my for loop to finish before reloading data on tableview? Swift

Tags: swift

I haven't used swift in a while but wanted to mess around with the new PHPicker and try my hands on it
I have a simple app that takes photos from the user's library and present them in a tableview
I use a simple bar button to prompt the user for images to use but when I add the images the first time the array comes up empty but the second time it uses the images from the first go.
I'm doing something wrong but I can't tell what it is please help!

```
import Photos
import PhotosUI
import UIKit

class PhotosListScreen: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    var tempPhotos = [UIImage]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
}

extension PhotosListScreen: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate,   UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func presentPhpicker() {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.selectionLimit = 0
        config.filter = PHPickerFilter.images
        
        let pickerViewController = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        pickerViewController.delegate = self
        self.present(pickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
            
    }
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult])  {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        for result in results {
            result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: { (object, error) in
                if let image = object as? UIImage {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tempPhotos.append(image)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        print("Selected image: \(tempPhotos)") // Empty the first time
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func addPhotos(_ sender: Any) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.presentPhpicker()
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tempPhotos.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let photo = tempPhotos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhotoCell") as! PhotoCell
        cell.setPhoto(photo: photo)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You add photos to tempPhotos asynchronously in completion handler , this may explain what when relodData (may be not in main queue)in dismiss you display only what was in tempPhotos before dismiss start.. execute relodData in main queue to synchronize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't wait**. Never wait for the result of an asynchronous operation.

If the order of the images doesn't matter just insert new rows when the images are available **inside** the closure

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult])  {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    for result in results {
        result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self, completionHandler: { (object, error) in
            if let image = object as? UIImage {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.tempPhotos.count, section: 0)
                    self.tempPhotos.append(image)
                    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [lastIndexPath], with:. automatic)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

A bonus is that the rows are inserted animated.